# Both hot and cold tub knobs leaking behind the wall

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

Okay, so I may have solved this problem but I want to know if my solution even made sense. We recently bought a house and soon realized (due to the ceiling being soaked downstairs) that our upstairs  bathtub was leaking. I figured out that the leak was dripping from both the hot and the cold knobs inside the wall but only when the water was turned on and running. I removed the spout (which was on pretty darn tight) and continued fiddling and realized that the water was no longer dripping inside the wall and there was also no more water downstairs on the floor while running the water. So I reapplied the spout but did not tighten it to the point where it was so tight that the handles moved towards me.. and it’s still not leaking.

So I guess my question is if the spout is on too tight can it cause the handles to leak water behind the wall?

I don’t know if this is a completely stupid question but I let the shower and spout run full blast for 15 minutes after loosening the spout and there is no water dripping and my floor downstairs is dry.

Thanks so much in advance !!!!

Comment: I had a bathtub leak.  It was the overflow drain, it hadn't been tightened enough to compress the gasket that keeps splashing water out.

Comment: Was your leak leaking from the drain? From the overflow? Or from the faucets?

Comment: it seems unlikely that the tightness of the spout connection would cause the valves to leak.

Comment: @Jasen, actually it could ... not the valves though, but a joint between pipes ... the OP said `it was so tight that the handles moved towards me` ... that means that the whole valve assembly could have been pulled out of alignment with the rest of the pipes

Comment: I also recreated the problem by tightening the spout to the point where the handles move towards me and water started leaking again. Considering I know very little about plumbing and I can’t see into that part of the wall to visualize the leak I have no idea if it’s possible.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like you have a good solution; would you add an answer to your question so others can benefit? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: " From the overflow?"  Yes.  There was a gap between the tub and overflow drain assembly water could get through.  It leaked during showers when water was splashing around.